# Could I skip all subsequent operators chain if condition is truthy in RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Is it possible in RxJS 5.5 to implement condition using some operator to skip all subsequent operators and emit some value (`false`)? For instance in this ng service method I would bypass bunch of this `.map` chain and provide `false` value immediately if `response.length === 0`:

```
getProjectDrivers(projectId): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('someUrl').pipe(
    // if (response.length === 0) { return false; and skip whole operator chain bellow}
    map((response: ProjectDriver[]) => response.filter((projectDriver: ProjectDriver) => projectDriver.streamName !== "AllRevenueStreamTotals")),
    map((response: ProjectDriver[]) => command => ({})
  )
)
.catch(this.handleError);
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you always can play with `switchMap`

```
  return this.http.get('someUrl').pipe(
    switchMap(response => {
      if (!response.length) {
        return of(null);
      } else {
        return of(result).pipe(
          map((response: ProjectDriver[]) => response.filter((projectDriver: ProjectDriver) => projectDriver.streamName !== "AllRevenueStreamTotals")),
          map((response: ProjectDriver[]) => command => ({}))
        )
      }
    }
  )
```